# Working out 3d destination based on angles and distance

Tags: c, geometry

I want to work out if I have an object in space, and I know how fast it will travel in a second and at what angle it is going, where it will end up on the x y and z.

`I have already tried using the same equation for x, and y, but neither quite come out right, and I think it is a logic error.

Idealy, I'd want to know: 1, how to calculate it. I'd expect a result of: {x, y, z} where x y and z are finishing coordinates.

Additional code:

```
dx=distance traveled on x
dy=distance traveled on y
dz=distance traveled on z:
xb = dx * sin(angle1);
y= dy * cos(angle1);
z= dz * cos(angle2);
```

Comment: This is basic vector math. Show us what you have.

Comment: You need two angles to specify a direction in 3D space, and you need to define how the angles relate to the axes.

Comment: added some code at the bottom there. The X and Y appear to work. The Z... not so much.

Comment: You probably want https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates (the x=, y=, z= formulas)

Comment: Assuming you have two angles, the vertical angle will give you the speed in the Z direction, and the speed in the horizontal plane, which in turn will give you the speed in the X and Y directions from the horizontal angle.

Comment: @lara: The comment of @Ian Abbott still applies despite your edit. What are `angle1` and `angle2`? Angles between what and what?